# Hello, when i try to print from my class, i get this error:

Tags: python, error-handling, printing

Code:

```py
class Passangers():
    def __init__(self, passangerNames, nationalities, age, gender):
        self.passangerNames = passangerNames 
        self.nationalities = nationalities 
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender 
    def data_base_update(self):  
        passanger_list =  self.passangerNames + " " + self.nationalities + " " + self.age + "" + self.gender 
        
passangers_return = Passangers("fdgfdg", "dfgdfgdf", "dfgfdg", "dfgfdgff",)
print(passangers_return.data_base_update)
```

Error:

```
<bound method Passangers.data_base_update of <__main__.Passangers object at 0x00000241A2467C70>>
```

I get this, but i dont get the print message

Comment: That's not an error message, that's what you requested to be printed. You printed the bound method object.  To print the result of calling that bound method you need to put parenthesis after it `print(passangers_return.data_base_update())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you actually call the method. The way you are doing it, you are just referencing the function object. Instead do, `print(passangers_return.data_base_update())`

In addition, if you are wanting to get `passanger_list` back from the function, add `return passanger_list` at the bottom of the function. Or you can return the string directly by placing the string concatenation you assigned to `passanger_list` directly after `return`. To continue, you should use *f-strings*. They allow you to embed variables and expressions inside strings: `return f"{self.x=}"` for example.

For your case:

```
def data_base_update(self):
    return f"{self.passangerNames} {self.nationalities} {self.age} {self.gender}"
```

### Pro Tip

You can use `__str__` (or `__repr__`) to display the string representation of your object!

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.passangerNames} {self.nationalities} {self.age} {self.gender}"
```

Now you can just pass your variable holding the instance to `print` and get the return value from `__str__` (or `__repr__`) as output!